# output phrase from the keyboard Java

Tags: java, keyboard, output, custom-keyboard

I would like to know how to output something onto the keyboard from a thread so other applications can pick it up. I couldn't find any information on google on how to do this. Does anyone know?

Comment: The keyboard is an input device. How would you output something to it?

Comment: If you're looking for a way to generate system-wide key events. I'm afraid you can't do that in `java`

Comment: @Titus That is disappointing. I was hoping to make my application work on any OS. I'm gonna try JNI and if that fails, C++. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You can use Robot class, check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: @11thdimension That is right. You can generate key events. I've forgot about that. Sorry BallisticBlaze for misleading you. For some reason I was thinking about listening for key events, which is impossible in Java.

Comment: @11thdimension Thank you. Can you make it an answer to this question so others can benifit from this question? Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, I will try to post it today.